# Boundary maps of the projective plane as a $\Delta$-complex (homology)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

Hi,
very simple question here. In Hatcher's 'Algebraic Topology' the diagram above is used to describe the projective plane as a $\Delta$-complex(see p.102). Later the 2-boundary maps are given by $\partial_2(U) = -a+b+c$ and $\partial_2(L)=a-b+c$. Can someone explain why e.g. $\partial_2(L)$ may not be $-a+b-c$? The way it is described by Hatcher we traverse the 2-simplex $U$ in counter clockwise order and $L$ in clock wise order. But is there a simple argument to see that we have to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is each simplex has a defined order given by the order inherited by the sub-simplices:
[image]

A simplex always looks the same. In case of the projective plane in the diagram, they are just arranged in a convenient way, such that the gluing map of the boundaries exactly is the one needed to result in the desired space.

In case of $\Delta^2$-simplices it is easy to see the orientation by just starting with the vertex that has two outgoing arrows. Call it $v_0$ for example. The vertex with two incoming arrows is the last one $v_2$.

So each simplex has a description eg. $[v_0 v_1 v_2 v_3 v_4]$

And you can simply apply the definition of the boundary map.

In case of a $\Delta^2$-simplex with vertices $[w_0 w_1 w_2]$ that would give:

$$\partial [w_0 w_1 w_2] = [w_1 w_2] - [w_0 w_2] + [w_1 w_2]$$

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so in particular the boundary of a 2-simplex always has to have two '+'-signs and one '-'-sign in its sum, because the boundary operator is defined as a alternating sum(starting with a '+'-sign)? Also your answer implies that the answer in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155407/orientation-and-simplicial-homology is wrong. Is that right?

Comment: @zref Yes, the boundary of a 2-simplex always has both signs: $\partial[v_0 v_1] = [v_1] - [v_0]$. The answer to the question there is not necessarily wrong it just uses the opposite orientation (all signs are opposite, this results in the same homology). The author writes himself "If the text instead writes it as a+b−c, it must use the opposite orientation on U, i.e. a clockwise, rather than counterclockwise, orientation"

Comment: @zref so basically your calculation "could" be ok too, but then you would have to change the orientation of all other simplices as well...  I recommend to just stick with the orientation provided by Hatcher, it will result in less confusion later

Comment: @zref as an exercise though, calculate the homology groups of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ once like this, then reverse the orientations and calculate the homology again, see that they are the same...

Comment: The author in the other thread wrote later on that in the case of the torus we have $\Delta(U) =-\Delta(L)$, whereas in the Hatcher we have $\Delta(U)=\Delta(L)$.But I suppose that not both ways can be correct, right?

Comment: @zref I think that makes no difference as they are just $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations. $\Delta_n(X)$ is the free abelian group of n-simplices ...